# Remapping org-agenda-transient-mode in spacemacs

Tags: spacemacs, wsl

The org-agenda-transient mode in spacemacs is mapped by default to M-SPC. Since I am running spacemacs in a wsl-g setup, this key is not available, since this is a default key mapping of windows and is not available in wsl-g windows.

I found the configuration of this transient mode in the setup of spacemacs for org, but I could not understand, how it works and how I would remap this. Normally I would remap a key by using a function, but the transient mode is not declared using a function..

Any idea how this could be done without redefining the whole hydra for the transient mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching `org-agenda-transient` in Spacemacs, I find that `M-SPC` is bound to `spacemacs/org-agenda-transient-state/body`, see these [lines](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/b74da79dbbd8573ab4f43721c74014d6f54d8bd0/layers/%2Bemacs/org/packages.el#L621-L622).

So `spacemacs|define-transient-state` will generate a function that ends with `/body` to activate the transient state.
I think you may remap like this (untested):

```lisp
(with-eval-after-load 'org-agenda
  (evilified-state-evilify-map org-agenda-mode-map
      :mode org-agenda-mode
      :bindings
      (kbd "M-SPC") nil
      (kbd "s-M-SPC") nil
      (kbd "x-x-x") 'spacemacs/org-agenda-transient-state/body))
```

Comment: That does not seem to work.  I get the following error: "wrong type argument: commandp, spacemacs/org-agenda-transient-state/body"

Comment: @bombadil Where the config did you put in? Could you try putting it in `with-eval-after-load`?

Comment: Yes. I did try this in multiple ways including `with-eval-after-load` and they all fail in the same way

Comment: emm, this is weird.

Comment: this actually works. I had another issue creating problems